# NestJs - GraphQL - Customize subscriptions port (for Apollo Server)

Tags: websocket, server, graphql, nestjs, subscription

The docs mention that you change the listener port for GraphQL subscriptions: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions#customize-subscriptions-server

However the linked docs don't show any way to do this.

The problem is that I already have a WebSocket server running on say, port 3333. I want to have Apollo listen to subscriptions on port 4444 so they don't clash. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan - Unfortunately not, I had to reconfigure the app around to accommodate the default port.

Comment: Yes, I had to change the Gateway port so that subscriptions can use the same port as the graphQL server. Thanks for your answer :-)